# How String[] args different from String... args in the main method?

Tags: java, string, program-entry-point

I got confused when I saw these two techniques through which we can pass our command line argument in main method.

I have seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301563/difference-fnstring-args-vs-fnstring-args) in stackoverflow but still I don't get it.

My doubt is which is efficient between these two ways.

1.In first we are calling main and assigning parameter as a string array
2.In second we are calling main with variable no of arguments.

Comment: A `String...` is syntactic sugar. It's actually wrapped in an `String[]` when it's passed into the method.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Comment: syntactic sugar?? didn't get you .

Comment: The parameter is a `String` array in both cases.

Comment: @Satya ie a more "eye friendly" way to write the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that if you want to invoke the main method of a class that isn't the entry point, it's easier:

```
class MyProgram1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyProgram2.main(new String[] {"arg1", "arg2", "arg3"})
    }
}
```

vs:

```
class MyProgram1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyProgram2.main("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear @Eric Which is efficient and when we use String... args[]??

Comment: @Satya: It's your main method. It's called once. You do __not__ care about the efficiency of that invocation. You use `String... args[]` when you want the error `legacy array notation not allowed on variable-arity parameter`. You use `String[]... args` when you want to pass a variable number of string arrays.